# Where will the Black rukh go to? Do Heaven and Hell exist?

Tags: magi

There are two kind of [rukh](http://magi.wikia.com/wiki/Rukh) in *Magi* universe. But first, let me explain what is rukh. SO basically, the rukh is:

> Rukh is the home of souls. While we live, it is every man for them
>   self. But when you die, all go back to one place, This is Rukh. When
>   humans die, their bodies return to the earth don't they? The souls
>   return to Rukh, The home of souls.

And there is *Black Rukh*, which mean the polar opposite of Rukh. It is created when one goes against fate and tries to defy destiny. It is created from and fuels hatred and malice.

According that, we know that the true rukh at the end, will come to one place called *home of souls*, but what happens to Dark Rukh? Where will their souls go? Do they go to Hell or something? And what is the *home of souls*, is it what we would call Heaven?

Comment: This question asks about major story reveal of Magi. It is all explained in the Manga, and answering this question here would take a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Short answer: No, no hell and heaven, at least not in the biblical sense. Much, much more complicated. Idea for spoiler: Why do all people in the Magi universe speak the same language except for a small group of tribes?

Comment: I have read magi until sinbad want to change the system of rukh at the holy palace/sacred palace when he met UGO the true almighty in magi universe , and then sinbad  finally got beaten and appear david as dark rukh of sinbad. Bjt i still dont understamd where will the dark rukh went to, since sinbad rukh went to home of souls, but where will david rukh went ? @SK19

Comment: I can't say for sure from the top of the head, but I assume dark rukh goes to the old god.